# Showing delete button on swipe uitableviewcell like favourites

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am using following code

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return YES if you want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        //add code here for when you hit delete
    }
}

-(void)swipePressed:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.myTable];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.myTable indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];
    if (indexPath == nil)
        NSLog(@"long press on table view but not on a row");
    else
    {
        [[self.myTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setEditingAccessoryType: UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete];
    }
}
```

the swipePressed is run but no Delete button shows up...

Comment: Just edited my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to install a swipe gesture recognizer in order to implement the swipe-to-delete functionality of a UITableView. This functionality is provided to you for free by the UITableView delegate. That is also not the correct use of `setEditingAccessoryType`. Remove the swipe gesture recognizer and method completely, then implement the method:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
```